# Trouble install node.js with homebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install Node.js with Homebrew (I installed it previously without using brew, and I've tried deleting all of those files). I've looked at previous questions asking similar things, but I haven't been able to get them to work. First I tried `brew link node` which gave me:

```
myusername@c126h060:~$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.6... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
Target /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

And then when I run `brew link --overwrite node` I get the following:

```
myusername@c126h060:~$ brew link --overwrite node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.6... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.
```

Additionally, when I tried using `brew link -n node` to find files to manually delete, I managed to delete some of them, but I'm still left with the following files that I can't delete:

```
myusername@c126h060:~$ brew link -n node
Would link:
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/npm
/usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local/include/node
/usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
```

When I try to delete I get the following (same thing for all of these files):

```
myusername@c126h060:~$ rm /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/npm
rm: /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/npm: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

It may be that you don't actually own your systemtap directory. Navigate to `/usr/local/share` and run this command in order to make yourself the owner:

```
chown -R <yourusername>:<yourgroupname> systemtap
```

When I was fixing this same issue earlier today, I had to also go into `/usr/local` and do the same thing for the lib directory.

Comment: do not forgot about "sudo". 
sudo chown -R <yourusername>:<yourgroupname> systemtap

Comment: I am getting systemtap: "No such file or directory".

I am using macOS sierra.

Comment: hmm, giving the complete path, /usr/local/share/systemtap/ worked

Comment: can someone give an example of the chow line without the placeholders? I don't want to input the wrong things. thanks in advance

Comment: ```sudo chown -R victor:admin systemtap``` perfectly worked for me !! Successfully upgraded my node to v14.8.0 :)

Answer (score 27):

get your username,

and get your groups:(could be more than one,generally is 'admin')

```
whoami
groups
```

then, for exapmle:

```
sudo chown -R chrislee:admin /usr/local/share/systemtap/
```

Answer (score 23):

Or, alternatively, verify the ownership and permissions on systemtap

```
$ ls -al /usr/local/share/systemtap/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102 Oct 23 18:06 .
drwxrwxr-x  15 root  wheel  510 Oct 24 20:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   68 Oct 24 20:17 tapset
```

then add yourself to the owner group (in this case wheel)

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/wheel GroupMembership <username>
```

then change the permissions on tapset to allow group edits

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/
```

Answer (score 23):

What worked for me:

1. `cd /usr/local/share`
2. `sudo chown -R <user>:<group> systemtap` (Did 1 & 2 for `/usr/local` too)

Above steps were failing. Went to next answer. Tried;

`ls -al /usr/local/share/systemtap/`
which throwed a 'Not found error.'

Then: `brew link node` was throwing an error. So I did:

3. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
4. `brew postinstall node -v`
5. And at last `brew link node`
6. `node -v` :)

So basically I removed all `node_modules/` folders and redid everything.

Answer (score 12):

```
arun:~$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.6... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
Target /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'
```

**Run below commands**

```
brew postinstall node -v
brew link node
```

Answer (score 3):

The following recipe worked for me:

1. Add your username to add group wheel `sudo dscl . append /Groups/wheel GroupMembership username`
2. `sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/`
3. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
4. `brew cleanup`
5. `brew link node`
6. `brew uninstall --force node`
7. `brew install node`

Then check version with `node -v` and `npm -v`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please keep in mind the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your post accordingly, e.g. by adding more explanation why your solution worked.

Comment: These steps worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This command was the answer for the error message for me. It changes the folder permissions to the current user:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/systemtap
```

Answer (score 0):

just add sudo in the beginning of the command npm install expo-cli --global

like `sudo npm install expo-cli --global` and hit enter.

hope it'll help you.